# Creating a cartesian product with the Django ORM

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-views

I currently have three tables; `Person`, `Item` and a many to many mapping table called `PersonItems`.

I am looking to output an HTML  table of all `Person`s down the left column, then the table header will be the `Item`s. A person may or may not have the item based on an entry in the `PersonItems` table, which I will indicate in the corresponding cell.

Ultimately I will have an HTML table output form a Django template containing Person multiplied by Item 'td' elements. There could be up to about 5000 persons, but only around 30 Items.

I aimed to produce this table by creating a cartesian between `Person` and `Item`, and for each combination, checking if there is an entry in the PersonItem table.

The problem I'm having is creating a cartesian product of the Person and Items table, which is then joined against the `PersonItems`. The only way I can see to do this without SQL is to iterate all `Person`s, and for each person perform a query to see if the person has the item. However that approach is quite a bit slower than using a raw SQL query.

I have experimented with the iteritems.product function to create the initial cartesian i.e.

```
product(Person.objects.all(), Item.objects.all())
```

then iterating this to check if there is a corresponding PersonItem record, however it's noticeably slower on the front end.

I don't particularly want to stick a big SQL query into my Django view, I am new to Django and it seems this is probably not the best direction to go in. If it can't be done as efficently using the Django ORM and/or Python, I'll just stick with the SQL i.e approximately the following query (note the cartesian subquery).

```
SELECT something,something,something
FROM (SELECT p.id as person_id, i.id as item_id, etc, etc, etc
      FROM Person p, Item i) x
LEFT JOIN person_item pi ON x.person_id = pi.person_id AND x.event_id = pi.event_id
```

Database is MySQL by the way, not that that should make a difference.

Comment: Can you share your *models* (well at least the `ForeignKey`s)? This looks like a *prefetch_related* case.

Comment: Hi Willem, I can't see how to edit my question. Yes I thought prefetch_related, but I'm not yet properly understanding it. Ideally I would perform a join that incorporated all rows from Person, Items and PersonItems, regardless of whether there was a mapping in PersonItems. SQL it's easy, by just leaving off the WHERE. Ultimately, my HTML table needs to be explicit if there is no linkage.  PersonItems looks like this: person = models.ForeignKey(Person, models.DO_NOTHING, blank=True, null=True)   item = models.ForeignKey(Item, models.DO_NOTHING, blank=True, null=True)